# Make appear an image when the mouse is on a text

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to make an image appear when I hover a text. The image doesnt't have to appear instead of the text but at an other place.

The idea is the following : when I hover the word "Google", the logo Google have to appear in the red box, when I hover the word "OneNote", the logo OneNote have to appear in the red box.
[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTm6B.png)

I tried to do it following this logical :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="img1" onmouseover="setImg()" onmouseout="unSetImg()" src="https://i1.wp.com/www.grapheine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/nouveau-logo-google.gif?fit=1950%2C1200&quality=90&strip=all&ssl=1" width="300">
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setImg(){
            document.getElementById("img1").src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSU48ifXX9Kar3IFVrlfwx6UFLqaQno8rCebFvGtwk6yWky9_mz";
        }

        function unSetImg(){
            document.getElementById("img1").src="https://i1.wp.com/www.grapheine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/nouveau-logo-google.gif?fit=1950%2C1200&quality=90&strip=all&ssl=1";
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Then it works but only when we replace an img by an other img but if I adapt my code replacing the img google by a text, it doesn't work !

Can someone say me what to use because I didn't find anything that match with what I want !

Thank You

Lucas

Comment: Is it an option to instead use CSS? You should be able to do it without JS, depending on the structure and goal.

Comment: "but if I replace the img by a text, it doesn't work"--> what do you mean by this? which image are you replacing by a text?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt good question .

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Fix that first.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i modified this sentence. I mean, i tried to replace the logo google by a text and this doesn't work, the text doesn't change to the logo onenote !

Comment: In addition, the `<img>` tag does not need and does not use a closing slash.

Comment: Okay but my first question was not really : show me the good practices in HTML x), but ty I edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the img src in a data-attribute on the element that will be hovered. Then on hover, set the img.src to the `data-logo` of the hovered element.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#thing li");
var logo = document.querySelector("#thing .logo");
elems.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    logo.src = elem.getAttribute("data-logo");
  });
  elem.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    logo.src = "";
  });
});
```

```css
img.logo {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  height: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thing">
  <img class="logo" />
  <ul>
    <li data-logo="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png">Google</li>
    <li data-logo="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/images/onenotelogobgs.png">OneNote</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, ty so much !

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hovercontainer {
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            height: 170px;
        }
                  .hovercontainer p{
                    position:absolute;
                    top:50%;
                    text-align: center;
                    left:0;
                    right:0;
                    margin:0 auto;  
                    z-index:10;
                  }
           .hovercontainer img{
            width:90%;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        opacity:0;
                  position: relative;}
        .hovercontainer p:hover ~ img{
         opacity:1
        }
                  .hovercontainer p:hover{
                    opacity:0;
                  }
```

```html
    <div class="hovercontainer">
                    <p>Text</p>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSU48ifXX9Kar3IFVrlfwx6UFLqaQno8rCebFvGtwk6yWky9_mz" alt="" />
                    </div>
```

Comment: That's not really what I expected but ty for your time !